Did Joe Biden refer to himself as a black woman?
The Telegraph claims that Joe Biden has made the statement on Philadelphia radio station

“By the way, I’m proud to be, as I said, the first vice-president, first black woman… to serve with a black president,”

The site has an audio recording, but given that audio is easy to fake, I'm wondering.
Did he make this statement?

The Biden campaign gave Andrea Lawful-Sanders 8 questions, of which she agreed to ask Biden 4 of the questions in a pre-recorded interview that was broadcast by WURD radio of Philadelphia on 04 July 2024.  WURD has an online version (Archive link) where the relevant portion begins at 13:40.  (Alternative Roll Call link to full interview since WURD deleted. Alternative youtube link)
Biden is speaking in a very choppy manner and listening to the whole interview it is understood that he isn't really meaning that he is a Black woman.
Biden says:

They should be in jail, and by the way I'm proud to be, as I said, the first vice president, the first Black woman [Lawful-Sanders says "mmhhm"] to serve with a Black president, I'm proud [to have a role in ?] the first Black woman [on ?] the Supreme Court

Listening to the whole interview, "as I said" refers back to Biden previously saying (around 8:30 in the online version) that he appointed the first Black vice-president and served under a Black president.  Overall, people listening to the whole interview would understand that Biden is having trouble forming sentences at times, despite having known the questions in advance, but wouldn't consider him as referring to himself as Black or as a woman.

Update
WURD Radio has now canceled Andrea Lawful-Sanders and made the following statement about the interview:

On July 3, the first post-debate interview with President Joe Biden was arranged and negotiated independently by WURD Radio host Andrea Lawful-Sanders without knowledge, consultation or collaboration with WURD management. The interview featured pre-determined questions provided by the White House, which violates our practice of remaining an independent media outlet accountable to our listeners. As a result, Ms. Lawful-Sanders and WURD Radio have mutually agreed to part ways, effective immediately.

...

Agreeing to a pre-determined set of questions jeopardizes that trust and is not a practice that WURD Radio engages in or endorses as a matter of practice or official policy.

...

...mainstream media has historically ignored, marginalized and stereotyped Black people in their coverage. ... This practice of de-legitimizing Black voices continues today. WURD Radio is not a mouthpiece for the Biden or any other Administration.


I don't see how the update to the answer is relevant to the question or the original answer.

@pipe Speaking that way in a choreographed interviewed seems different from being surprised by a question and misspeaking. Part of the claim in the question is "made the statement on Philadelphia radio station" and this is further confirmation and explanation from the radio station.

This answer comes down to: it is understood that "he isn't really meaning" it. So apparently he did indeed say it, correct? (Or else any discussion about "meaning it" would not apply, I mean...)

@JosBergervoet yes, I agree

@pipe The link to original audio source is satisfactory answer.

@pinegulf Too bad it’s non-functional.

@user3840170 Sure, but it was functioning when I accepted the answer. Try archive link: https://archive.is/RDyzW

@JosBergervoet The title question is "Did he refer to himself as a black woman?" and the answer to that is No. The question body is did he make the statement with those words and the answer to that is Yes. So the context is relevant.

@user3067860 Could you elaborate, then, how how he does refer to himself in: "By the way I'm proud to be as I said the first black President first black woman to serve with a black President". Is he identifying as the first black President, you mean perhaps?!

@JosBergervoet This answer already elaborates on this--in context he's talking about how he's proud to have served with the first black president and appointed the first black woman to the supreme court. The words got mixed up but it's clear in context what the intended meaning is. Like if I'm speaking and I start a thought "so, you can see when you" and then I change what I'm saying in the middle of the sentence "but, actually that doesn't matter", it should be clear that I'm not calling you a butt even though I have technically said "you but".

@user3067860 That is totally not answering what I asked, and is seems weird: why should we be interested in chopping up things that have been said in partial sentences and then reordering them to something else? With enough fantasy that would give infinitely many meanings. It seems you are completely mistaken about the relevance of context. Context can serve to correct small errors, but it is not (as you explicitly require here) a free pass to change the meaning into anything that suits you.

@JosBergervoet if Biden's pattern is getting his thoughts and phrases out of order, recognizing that could help with a diagnosis.  Like when he said "I'm the first president that got elected statewide in the state of Delaware, when I was a kid" he was originally talking about people supposedly not liking Catholics when he was a kid.

@JosBergervoet Context is the punctuation of spoken English. It's the difference between "Let's eat, Grandpa!" and "Let's eat Grandpa!" Do you genuinely believe Biden was referring to himself as a black woman or are you just trolling at this point?

@user3067860 What do you mean by "just"? What is usually called a Socratic dialogue (forcing opponents to think critically) is now denoted by some as "trolling", but giving it another name does not make it less valuable! (Like, calling democracy "populism" does not make it inferior, although some might wish so...) And solving ambiguities in punctuation (as you mention) is exactly how context can serve to correct small errors, as I mentioned! But in the sentence I quoted (5 comments up from here) Biden still says that he is the first black President. How do you fix that with punctuation?

@JosBergervoet Your quote is false.  He did not say “first Black president”.  He said “first vice president”.

Thanks, @DavePhD that is at least addressing what I asked (6 comments up from here) and what was evaded by user3067860. So with that correction to the quote, can we be sure that Biden identifies as the first black female vice President? (I just wanted to be sure, that's all! Also: do you know what preferred pronoun should be used now for Biden?!)

@JosBergervoet No, it’s like saying you went to the grocery store to get “coffee, ice, cream…” vs “coffee, ice cream…” vs “coffee ice cream…”. Biden is at the end of the interview and trying to rattle off his list of accomplishments to a Black radio station.  In his cognitive condition he is mixing up ideas as he speaks and “the first Black woman” is at least partially a separate item in the list from “the first vice president”.

@DavePhD Of course that all is true, but in questions about how people identify themselves (which is what I asked) we should not be distracted by true facts. What you write does not rule out that he identifies as the first black female President of Ukraine (called Putin). "Identifying" is a choice, and we should respect that choice. But first we must know what the choice is, that's why I asked! (And to know what "is" is, is another question, fortunately already answered by another President.)

"WURD Radio has now canceled Andrea Lawful-Sanders...." I know that these days, it is fashionable to declare that people, places and objects can be "canceled" whenever they suffer any negative consequence whatsoever, but traditionally, the word that would be used here is "fired," while her radio show might have been canceled (but more likely was retained with a different host).

@Obie2.0 I can't say "fired" because it was by mutual agreement.  Also, I don't know for sure if she was an employee versus a contractor.

The Economist makes an educated guess as to the meaning of his mangled sentences:

He [Biden] is more vigorous when speaking off a teleprompter, but when not using one has a tendency to mangle his words. During a recent radio interview he declared, “I’m proud to be, as I said, the first vice-president, first black woman, to serve with a black president.” (He apparently had been trying to say that he was proud to serve as Barack Obama’s vice-president, and also proud to be the first president with a black female vice-president.)

-- The Economist, Joe Biden’s ABC interview will not quell doubts about his future
Note: Barack Obama identifies himself as black man. Biden's vice president is Kamala Harris, who identifies as black woman.

Welcome to skeptics. We try to find the answer to the specific question asked. Inferring further (political) implications lead to swamp of internet hatewars.

OK, for Harris and Obama it's clear, but does Biden identify himself as a black woman?

Your answer here doesn't address the question directly, nor does it provide direct evidence that would prove it either way. Are there any sources that do this? If not, maybe that's something worth mentioning.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you do not understand, that is on you. Biden clearly mangled his sentences and his words had a meaning different from a direct reading. I have provided a reputable source.
